# iOS Initializing a detail View Controller

Tags: ios, initialization, viewcontroller

What's the best way to setup a "detail" ViewController? Say I have a very simple DetailViewController with a UILabel. It has an API (this is psuedo code to demostrate the concept):

```
UpdateLabel(string text)
{
  this.label.text=text;
}
```

So in the parent ViewController, I have:

```
PrepareForSegue(UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
{
  base.PrepareForSegue(segue, sender);
  DetaiViewController.UpdateLabel("Hello");
}
```

However, this crashes because "label" is null in the detail View controller because ViewDidLoad has not been called yet. I know this can be fixed by adding something liek this in UpdateLabel

```
UpdateLabel(string text)
{
  this.View.Hidden=this.View.Hidden; // To force view to load
  this.label.text=text;
}
```

but that seems very hacky.

Alternatively, I could change UpdateLabel to just store the string:

```
UpdateLabel(string text)
{
   this.textString.text=text;
}
```

and then initialise the label in ViewDidLoad:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() 
{
   base.ViewDidLoad();
   this.label.text=this.textString;
}
```

BUT what if i want the parent controller to modifiy the label later? Calling UpdateLabel will only update the textString variable and wont change the label.

Whats the correct approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You `init` the `UIViewController` and pass the text, store it, and on `viewDidLoad` you update the `UILabel`.
2. You can then update the `UILabel` by exposing it to other classes (as a property for example).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but that doesn't sound like a very good API. Effectively we'd have InitLabel and UpdateLabel and it still isn't clear when it's safe to call UpdateLabel, eg InitLabel immediately followed by UpdateLabel will still crash.

Comment: Well, being using this pattern for some time and I don't have any issue with it. On `viewDidLoad`you can call the method you use to update your `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the detail view controller update its views whenever it is about to be shown.

If the detail view is shown not by the result of a segue, like when you use a tab bar for example, and the viewDidLoad is not called, you could make the parent controller be the delegate of the detail view controller and on viewWillAppear you call the delegate method to update the detail view controller. After that the detail view controller updates its view/subviews.

This way you give a chance to the parent controller make changes.

Don't know if that is the best alternative for you...